# can't insert into mysql database using visual basic form

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to insert user data into mysql database using the below visual basic code but i just get my MessageBox saying "Registered Successfully!" and no change has been done to the user database table
Note: i have imported MySql.Data.MySqlClient and initiated each of Conn, Cmd, Cmd1 and Rdr

```
Private Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click
    Conn = New MySqlConnection
    Conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=mmmsss123;database=gymdb"

    txtUName.Text = txtUName.Text.ToLower()
    txtUName.Text = txtUName.Text.Replace(" ", "")
    txtPassword.Text = txtPassword.Text.ToLower()
    txtPassword.Text = txtPassword.Text.Replace(" ", "")

    Try
        Conn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from gymdb.user where username='" & txtUName.Text & "'"
        Cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, Conn)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader

        Dim Count As Integer = 0

        While Rdr.Read
            Count += 1
        End While
        Rdr.Close()

        Conn.Close()

        If Count >= 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("This Username Is Already Registered!" & Environment.NewLine & "Please Enter Another Username", "Registeration State")
        Else
            If txtUName.Text <> "" And txtPassword.Text <> "" Then
                Conn.Open()
                Query = "insert into gymdb.user (username, upassword) values ('" & txtUName.Text & "', '" & txtPassword.Text & "')"
                Cmd1 = New MySqlCommand(Query, Conn)
                MessageBox.Show("Registered Successfully!", "Registeration State")
                Conn.Close()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Not Valid Username Or Password!" & Environment.NewLine & "Please Enter Valid Username And Password", "Registeration State")
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!")
    Finally
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: A command needs to be executed to perform what you have written in the command text. Missing Cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery. By the way the line Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery when you want to SELECT some data is not required and is totally useless

Comment: And an advice. Learn how to use parameters if you want to avoid many problems with sql code.

Comment: you are right Mr. Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:
Missing

```
Cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```